# what does severing the ties of kinship mean?

Tags: relationships

My family has many uncles and aunts and It is not possible to contact with them frequently and they live very far away from us. Will it be severing the ties of kinship if I don't contact with some of them or is it enough to contact with  some of them?
Which people actually deserves the ties of kinship most?
Jazakallah Khairan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Praise be to Allah,

Severing the the ties of kinship means to break or cut the relationship with relatives (any of them). We must keep good relationship with all of our relatives, be VERY good and kind to them, visit them if one is able to and keep in contact with them in any way you can. Giving gifts to them and writing letters to them if one is not able to visit them or calling them on the phone or texting them. Breaking the relationship with one’s relatives is one of the MAJOR sins in Islam even if their relatives are very mean. We treat our relatives kindly and forgive them. Allah says in the Qur’an in Surah Muhammad that one who breaks the relationship with one’s relatives, Allah will CURSE them

“Such are they whom Allah has cursed, so that He has made them deaf and blinded their sight”

[Muhammad 47:22]

Our Prophet Muhammad (s) said that one who cuts the relationship with their relatives will NOT ENTER HEAVEN

“No one who cuts the relationship with relatives will enter Heaven.”
[Sahih Muslim]

We must keep good relationship will all of our relatives.

May Allah (SWT) help us to do all which pleases him

Comment: How often should I text them? Do I need to contact with my cousins? Is it obligatory?

Comment: Yes it is obligatory to have a good relationship with them and ALL of your relatives and contact them

Comment: How often should I do this

Answer (score 0):

Severing kinship is haram, therefore, what it means is one falls into a state of sin whenever he does until he repents. Besides, families have huge [advantages](https://www.islamiqate.com/3312/what-are-the-advantages-of-a-family) and they are crucial to the Islamic society.